# fread hangs when trying to ready from stdout of process opend with proc_open in PHP

Tags: php, linux, gsm, at-command, modem

I am using PHP to control a GSM modem connected to a Raspberry PI via USB, running PHP 7.3.31 and:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 5.10.63-v7l+ #1459 SMP Wed Oct 6 16:41:57 BST 2021 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

I am able to run this command to connect and interact with the modem:

```
cu -s 115200 -l /dev/ttyUSB3
```

when I run that command directly from bash, I see this output:

```
Connected.
```

However if I attempt to connect using proc_open and read this output, fread hangs:

```
<?php
$descriptors = [['pipe', 'r'], ['pipe', 'w'], ['file','errors.txt','a']];
$handle = proc_open('cu -s 115200 -l /dev/ttyUSB3', $descriptors, $pipes);
stream_set_blocking($pipes[1],1);
$world = fread($pipes[1],1);
var_dump($world);
```

I would expect the above code to print the letter "C".

If I change the command to the following:

```
cu -v
```

then the output is:

```
cu (Taylor UUCP) 1.07
Copyright (C) 1991, 92, 93, 94, 1995, 2002 Ian Lance Taylor
This program is free software; you may redistribute it under the terms of
the GNU General Public LIcense.  This program has ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
```

If I run that command from the PHP script like this:

```
<?php
$descriptors = [['pipe', 'r'], ['pipe', 'w'], ['file','errors.txt','a']];
$handle = proc_open('cu -v', $descriptors, $pipes);
stream_set_blocking($pipes[1],1);
$world = fread($pipes[1],1);
var_dump($world);
```

I see the output:

```
string(1) "c"
```

which is as I would expect, so there doesn't appear to be anything wrong with the PHP code and it seems to be able to read output from the cu command just fine.

I can see that errors are being correctly written to my error file because when I kill the script I can see the interrupt signal showing up in the error file. If I put in a loop checking the process status every second, it shows that it's running. If I kill the process from another screen it changes to not running.

Everything seems to suggest the command is running and connected but fread just hangs and never prints any output.

If I set the stream to not blocking it doesn't hang but it also doesn't return any output. I've also tried with fgets and stream_get_contents.

Comment: Check the content of `errors.txt`. Some outputs are written to stderr, not stdout.

Your `fread($pipes[1],1);` can only read the `['pipe', 'w']` aka stdout.

Comment: Yep "I can see that errors are being correctly written to my error file because when I kill the script I can see the interrupt signal showing up in the error file"

Comment: Also for some weird reason the pipes are in the opposite order they're passed in the descriptor spec. That is, you read from the write one, and write to the read one. It seems like it would make more sense to me if it were the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

Well apparently the answer to this question is "use Symfony". The Symfony Process component doesn't seem to have this problem. I have no idea what they're doing differently (their documentation states they're using proc_open under the hood and I haven't dug around to see how they do it) but whatever they're doing, it works, so if you happen to come across the same problem, then:

```
composer require symfony/process
```

Is your friend :)